# Unable to edit data created on primary node in mongodb after the node became secondary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using mongodb replica set in my rails application with 1 primary(node A) and 1 secondary node(node B).

It was working prefectly fine until i added one more node(node C) and made node C as primary. Now that primary node (node C) is having all the content but as per my observation content created on previous primary(node A) can only be read now but not edited or destroyed. As i have understood that data can only be written to primary node so i guess data from secondary(node A- earlier primary) can only be read while being accessed.

Is this a common behaviour or i'm missing something?

EDIT:
I took a db dump of replica set from the primary node(node C) and then `db.dropDatabase()` and  mongorestore again. I found data missing in some collections. Can anyone explain what could be the issue.

Comment: *how* did you make C the primary?  And what do you mean "C is having all the content" - all members of the replica set have all the same content.

Comment: i have changed the priority of C from mongo console, yes same thing the nodes are in sync. I took a db dump of primary and then tried to restore it locally. Some documents in collections was not available and found data missing. so it refers as the mongodump is not backing all the data and i'm not able to guess the reason

Comment: @AsyaKamsky you are associated with MonggoDB inc, can u please refer me some docs to have a deep understanding with mongodb

Comment: it's hard to tell what was going on here - how do you know this data wasn't missing before?  Why did you do dump and why did you do db.dropDatabase()?  I'm afraid I'm not following exactly what you did and exactly what problem you encountered (and how you know there was a problem - that information might help).  How did you make C primary?  Since things "worked" before then and didn't after, I would imagine something during the process of adding C and making it primary possibly caused a problem.

Comment: data wasn't missing before? -- Some user entries in my application was not present.I'm using a rails application so in some other collections also i checked entries were missing. As the last option, i took a backup of entire data, reason being that i wanted to recreate it so that all the write operations would happen at one place i.e primary.

Comment: yes but how do you know when it went 'missing'?  Was it successfully written initially?

Comment: Yes it was written initially as users were able to login perfectly fine. I had referred http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary/ to make the secondary as primary.

Comment: you can see if the data is missing from just the new primary or from all members by individually connecting to each member with mongo shell and issuing rs.slaveOk() and then commands to query for data to compare it.  I suspect that the data is missing from all the nodes - it would be very strange for it to only be missing from the new node as it would not have become primary until it had sync'ed all of the data from the old primary.

Answer (score 0):

In a mongodb replica set you can only write (modify, create, destroy) on the primary node. Writes are then propagated to other (secondary) nodes in the replica set. Note that this propagation may not be immediate.

However when the primary change you should be able to write on data previously written by another primary.

Note that when you add a node to a replica set, it's preferable to load the latest database backup within this node before. The replication process is based on an [oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) shared between each node that indicates creation/deletion/update, however this oplog has a limited number of entries. So earlier entries may not be considered by your new primary ...

Comment: As you say, it means every new node should have a db before it's being attached to primary. I see it as a pain and would be looking for a proper soln

Comment: it's quite easy to dump a mongodb database and restore it. Look for mongo dump and mongo restore you will find plenty of doc.

Comment: i have kept it as last option, like take a backup, clean the nodes and  restore. But i was just wondering if i need to add more secondary nodes with high priority, how things should fall in place

Comment: You don't actually need to clean all your nodes. Just prepare your new database, load a backup inside and then add it to your replica set. After a minutes your new node will be in total harmony with your replica set.

Comment: why does this matter?  You can add an empty DB node to a replica set and it will sync up to become current all by itself.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky agreed, i have updated the qsn, can u check it again and please help